# python Correlation matrix different combination

Tags: python, dataframe, correlation

Suppose I have one dataframe as below and I get the correlation matrix (facor 0 to factor 9). How can I get all different combination of factors' correlation matrix (e. g. three factors as a combination)? Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rs = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(rs.rand(10, 10))
corr = df.corr()
```

Comment: So you want some method to compute a 3dimensional correlation cube?

Comment: @HermanWilén yes

Comment: are you looking for `corr(X, Y, Z)` or `(corr(X,Y), corr(X,Z), corr(Y,Z))`? you'll probably have to write your own `corr` function for `corr(X, Y, Z)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 corr.iloc[[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
```

to get the first 3 factor correlations.